# Android Studio request json through php by passing a parameter to php

Tags: php, android, json

I'm using AsyncTask to request json data through php which is uploaded in AWS cloud. Below is my code:

`@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        new JsonTask().execute("http://XXX.qiykuanrge.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/index.php/?key=leg");
        return leg_state_view;
 }`

```
public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<CongressModel>> {
    @Override
    protected List<CongressModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
```

...

I got this error:

java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "csci571.qiykuanrge.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com": No address associated with hostname

my php looks like this:

```js
<?php
 date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

 if (isset($_GET["key"])) {

    if ($_GET["key"] == "leg") {
   $url = "http://104.198.0.197:8080/legislators?order=state__asc,last_name__asc&per_page=all&apikey=";
   $content = file_get_contents($url);
   echo $content;
  }
```

Does someone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Based on `java.net.UnknownHostException:`. I'm not sure that is error from PHP. There are 2 possible reason for this case:

1. You don't have internet access from android
2. The `host` is not accessible. Please try access this url http://csci571.qiykuanrge.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/key=leg from browser to make sure it is work.

Comment: I have add the proper internet access in my manifest.xml the link should be :http://csci571.qiykuanrge.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/index.php/?key=leg. I post it wrong, I will edit it now. The error remains..

Comment: As @DollyAswin stated, what do you get when trying to access that link from the phone's Browser? Do you get any response?

Comment: I have access the new url http://csci571.qiykuanrge.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/index.php/?key=leg and it give json as body response. It mean there is no problem with PHP. Seem the problem caused by there is no internet connection on Android

Answer (score 0):

most of the cases if `java.net.UnknownHostException` are internet problem. The host can't be verified if no internet connection. please check you internet speed is enough or not to make a request. do you run on your emulator or phone?

have you add this in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

if still no working

1. clear your cache
2. trim your url
3. encode your url